# printing word in a column b if the value in column a is above 1

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this code and it should check if the value in the column: friction_number is above 1 than it should print "gravel" for all the cells in which thats the case. I tried working with functions but then the order couldn't be the way it needs to be.
my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pygef.gef import ParseGEF

#Read *.gef file
gef = ParseGEF("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.Gef")
gef.df.to_csv("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF")
file = pd.read_csv("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF", usecols=['friction_number' , 'depth'])

print (file)
file["Soil type"] = Soil_type

for i in file.friction_number:
    if (i > 1):
        Soil_type = "Gravel"
else:
    Soil_type = "unknown"
print (file)
```

This prints:

depth  friction_number Soil type

0     1.60         1.498638   unknown

1     1.62         0.943396   unknown

2     1.64         0.909091   unknown

3     1.66         1.172708   unknown

4     1.68         1.585014   unknown

..     ...              ...       ...

329   8.18         0.693328   unknown

330   8.20         0.665844   unknown

331   8.22         0.646598   unknown

332   8.24         0.626465   unknown

333   8.26         0.605465   unknown

which is weird cause there are two cells inwhich the value is above 1, how can I solve this?

EDIT:
So, there are multiple soil types I have to add. How can I add a multiple different types (for example sand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'depth': {0: 1.6, 1: 1.62, 2: 1.64, 3: 1.66, 4: 1.68},
    'friction_number': {0: 1.498638, 1: 0.943396, 2: 0.909091, 3: 1.172708,
                        4: 1.585014}
})

df['Soil Type'] = np.where(df['friction_number'].gt(1), 'Gravel', 'unknown')

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   depth  friction_number Soil Type
0   1.60         1.498638    Gravel
1   1.62         0.943396   unknown
2   1.64         0.909091   unknown
3   1.66         1.172708    Gravel
4   1.68         1.585014    Gravel
```

---

Edit: For multiple types with multiple conditions use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy-select)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'depth': {0: 1.6, 1: 1.62, 2: 1.64, 3: 1.66, 4: 1.68},
    'friction_number': {0: 1.498638, 1: 0.943396, 2: 0.909091, 3: 1.172708,
                        4: 1.585014}
})

conds = [
    df['friction_number'].between(1, 1.5),
    df['friction_number'].gt(1.5)
]

labels = ['Gravel', 'Sand']

df['Soil Type'] = np.select(conds, labels, default='unknown')

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   depth  friction_number Soil Type
0   1.60         1.498638    Gravel
1   1.62         0.943396   unknown
2   1.64         0.909091   unknown
3   1.66         1.172708    Gravel
4   1.68         1.585014      Sand
```

Comment: thanks, this worked solved the first problem. But is there a way that is only returns it when the value is for example between 1 and 1.5?

Comment: `df['friction_number'].between(1, 1.5)`

Comment: okay that worked too, thank you soo much. One last question, lets say there is a second type "sand", that should be printed if friction_number > 1.5. what is the best way of implementing this?

Comment: The answer to that question is one that is fundamentally different than the one you've asked above. If I change my answer, it will no longer be a correct answer to the question you've asked. Would you mind updating your question to include the details of how you would like to categorize the data so that way the question and answer still match?

Comment: I edited it a little bit, is it alright this way?

Comment: Updated my answer to include multiple conditions and labels.

Comment: since, I dont have the ability to chat I want to thank you yet another time. I should be able to figure the rest out.